# getJSON works in Chrome, in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following JavaScript code works in Chrome, sometimes in IE (will explain below) but not in Firefox.

By not working I mean that the `alert` inside the function of the first `.getJSON` doesn't execute. No messages in the console.

*Note: the files that `.getJSON` retrieves are text files with two arrays of JSON objects. Nevermind that it has an `html` extension. That comes from an external system that I don't control.*

```
function loadAgentsData(totalRotationTime) {

var rowsPerPage = 20;
var fadeInTime =  300;
var fadeOutTime = 400;

var workgroups = [];
var rawUsers = [];

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });    

$.getJSON('JSMemberService.html', function(result) {

    alert('inside first getJSON');

    rawUsers = result.users;
    workgroups = result.workgroups;
    $.getJSON('JSLending.html', function(result) {
        rawUsers.push.apply(rawUsers,result.users);
        workgroups.push.apply(workgroups,result.workgroups);
        $.getJSON('JSESupport.html', function(result) {
            rawUsers.push.apply(rawUsers,result.users);
            workgroups.push.apply(workgroups,result.workgroups);

            // Calculate Workgroups Totals
            var totalWaiting  = 0;
            var totalAnswered = 0;
            var totalReceived = 0;
            for (i in workgroups) {
                totalWaiting  = totalWaiting  + parseInt(workgroups[i].waiting);
                totalAnswered = totalAnswered + parseInt(workgroups[i].answered);
                totalReceived = totalReceived + parseInt(workgroups[i].received);
            }

            $("#wg-waiting").text(totalWaiting);
            $("#wg-answered").text(totalAnswered);
            $("#wg-received").text(totalReceived);

            // Filter out users that are not logged in
            var loggedInUsers = rawUsers.filter(function(item) { return item.logged_in == "1" });

            // Calculate aggregate values for users and have one JSON object per user.
            var users = AggregateUsers(loggedInUsers);

            // Populate the HTML with the users' values

            PopulateUsers(sortedUsers,rowsPerPage,totalRotationTime,fadeInTime,fadeOutTime);


        }); // end of inner getJSON
    }); // end of middle getJSON
}); // end of outer getJSON
```

} // end of function loadAgentsData

Why would this not work in Firefox?
The funny thing is that while developing this I would open the `HTML` file in Firefox locally (without being served by IIS) and it worked fine. It wouldn't work in Chrome because it doesn't allow `ajax`ing local files.

Now to IE...
It works perfectly from one computer and it doesn't from another computer with exactly the same version of IE 11.0.9600.18763. 
In the computer that it doesn't work the console throws an error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'`.
How can it support it on one computer and not on the other with the same version of IE?

I remove the `filter` line and it still doesn't work, but now it's an `HTML` issue, I believe. The labels and values for Waiting, Answered and Received are all on top of each other! This is the HTML:

```
<div id="averageStatsRow">
<div class="workgroup_title_container">
   <div class="workgroup_title">Average Statistics</div>
</div>
<div id="workgroupLabels" class="label_container">
   <div class="thirds_divider">
      <div class="data_label">Interactions Waiting</div>
   </div>
   <div class="thirds_divider">
      <div class="data_label">Answered</div>
   </div>
   <div class="thirds_divider">
      <div class="data_label">Received</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="averageStats">
   <div class="thirds_divider">
      <div class="data_value" id="wg-waiting"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="thirds_divider">
      <div class="data_value" id="wg-answered"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="thirds_divider">
      <div class="data_value" id="wg-received"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm pulling my hair...

Comment: See Firefox's console for more information

Comment: Nothing on Firefox's console.

Comment: By "external system", do you mean that your code and that system is deployed on different domains? If so, do proxy pass with nginx or Apache

Comment: No. There's a certain service that places those files in the same folder where the `index.html` file is.

Comment: `$.getJSON('json.html', result=>alert('inside first getJSON'))` alerts for my firefox. Unable to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a server issue, but without understanding more about your configuration it's hard. I would suggest using `curl` on your command line to test out if `JSMemberService.html` returns the right JSON content.

Additionally, it should come with the response header `content-type` of `application/json`, you may also need your server to send `CORs` headers with the response. You might see different behavior in this case when viewing your page on your filesystem vs. being served by a webserver.

Regarding how the three data types render, we would need to see your full HTML and CSS for that, I think you should make a jsbin of the whole example.

Comment: It's IIS / Windows 2012 Server. Where do I set up those server side things?

Answer (score 0):

All my Internet Explorer issues were solved by adding this one line to the `head`:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

I don't have the solution to my Firefox issues.